# Recognised the type

Tags: typescript

I want to get the default option from a list of options.

```
type
export type Unpacked<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T;

interface
getDefaultValue?: <T extends Option[]>(options: T) => Unpacked<T>;
```

Example

```
const options = [
   {label: "New York", value: 38 }, 
   {label: "Washington", value: 39 }
]
then return type of getDefaultValue must be 38 | 39
```

Incorrect test is

```
getDefaultValue={(options: Option[]) => any string}
```

But I have got error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Unpacked<T>'.`

**UPD**

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-galileo-ndto7l?file=/src/App.tsx

```js
export type Unpacked<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T;

type Option = { label: string; id: number };

const getValues = <T extends Option[]>(anyOptions: T): Unpacked<T> => {
  return anyOptions[0].id;
};

const options: Option[] = [
  { label: "New York", id: 38 },
  { label: "Washington", id: 39 }
];

/** result must be any id from options.*/
/** In current case type of result must be 38 | 39 */
const result = getValues(options);

export default function App() {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: SOrry, there is still no `reproducible example`. Try to copy and paste your example to TS playground, you will get a lot of errors because syntax is not correct

Comment: My fault, added sandbox example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use different approach:

```js
type Option = { label: string; id: number };

const getValues = <
    Id extends number,
    Item extends Option & { id: Id },
    List extends Item[]
>(anyOptions: [...List]): List[number]['id'] => anyOptions[0].id;

// 38 | 39
const result = getValues([
    { label: "New York", id: 38 },
    { label: "Washington", id: 39 }
]);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgl3BN)

You need to infer literal type of `id` property. More information about function arguments inference you can find in my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Also, if you have an array and you want to infer elements, you need to use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)